# how can I align brief text below image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align my `demo` text below my image. I am currently using bootstrap, but how can I do align this below my image and `::after` between divs an icon `>`  [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42r7m.png)

```
<section>
    <h2 class="main-title">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Test process</font></font>
    </h2>
    <div class="container demo">
        <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="steps">
                <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" style="height: 80px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <h2 class="steps__title">How It Works</h2>
                <p>demo</p>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="steps">
                <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" style="height: 80px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <h2 class="steps__title">How It Works</h2>
                <p>demo</p>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="steps">
                <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" style="height: 80px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <h2 class="steps__title">How It Works</h2>
                <p>demo</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you are using very wrong Bootstrap.
Please research how to use container, row, flex and column on Bootstrap. Check this [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/). Secondly, always use separate divs in col.

That's my snippet check this and please that you preview full page.

```css
  .icon img {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .details h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:#515f7f;
  }

  .details p {
    margin-top: -5px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>arg0-container</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <section class="mt-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="icon d-flex">
            <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" height="80px" />
            <div class="details ml-4 mt-2 text-center d-block">
              <h2>How It <br> Works</h2>
              <p>Demo</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="ml-2 mt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="icon d-flex">
            <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" height="80px" />
            <div class="details ml-4 mt-2 text-center d-block">
              <h2>How It <br> Works</h2>
              <p>Demo</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="ml-2 mt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="icon d-flex">
            <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" height="80px" />
            <div class="details ml-4 mt-2 text-center d-block">
              <h2>How It <br> Works</h2>
              <p>Demo</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="ml-2 mt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you wanna make horizontal centered this section you should use to pl-5 class on section and col-md-4 tags.